# weird url using capybara and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

Hi I am trying to visit a URL in my tests using visit

```
before { 
    visit(packages_path(package))
    # visit packages_path package
}
```

both of these lines of code produce the error in my tests

> Failure/Error: visit(packages_path(package))
>        ActionController::RoutingError:
>          No route matches [GET] "/packages.515"

I'm expecting the url to be /packages/515 as per the [capybara API](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master#Navigating). I'm not sure what is happening here or why. Any help would be appreciated. I would like to avoid hardcoding the url if possible.

Comment: Looks familiar but I can't place it. Better show your routes.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a spelling mistake it should have been visit package_path package. Fixing this mistake solved the problem I was seeing.

Comment: this does provide the answer, the problem was caused by a spelling mistake in my code. After Dave Schweisguth's comment I checked the routes and realised my route was package not packages.